# Cumulative Sum & Rolling sql in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have below requirement & need help to build sql,

Total Enrollment [Sum Column1], [Prior to Month1 start]
Cumulative Sum Distinct/unique [Column1] over 13month rolling period based on date [M1,M2,M3,M4.......M13]
Date Format [YYYY-MM-DD]

Expecting cumulative sum starts with Total sum before month1

Comment: Can you provide some simple data and the expected outputs ? also can you share what have you tried so far

Comment: Check this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166562/rolling-sum-previous-12-months-per-month-sql-snowflake